# Methods of avoiding unintentionally wasting seed at night

Tags: halacha, history, talmud-gemara, sin, derabanan

Hi I heard there are methods of avoiding unintentionally wasting seed at night like sleeping on your side specifically that it has to be uncomfortable so your body doesn't sin in the night and then turning around in the middle of the night to the other side and other methods like this.

Is there any more strategies and fourms online that talk about this how to completely avoid this issue at night unintentionally?

Comment: Try guardyoureyes.com or nofap.com. But I don't think there's any way to complete stop nocturnal emissions.

Comment: @Harel13 the way the halacha and discussion is phrased around gazing inappropriately is that it leads to hirhurim which lead to emissions at night. Therefore if one comes to control his eyes and thoughts, he will not have any more emissions.

Comment: @RabbiKaii - it is not that simple. Whilst you are right that what we see during the day can sub-consciously effect our thoughts at night, sometimes it is due to having a full stomach of food and sleeping in certain positions where the heat generated etc. creates the stimulation. That is why sleeping on the side is suggested to prevent these emissions.

Comment: @Dov I'd be glad to see that inside if you have a reference for me? I'd also like to check what the issue is if there is an emission devoid of any hirhurum

Comment: As far as position of sleeping see Rambam - https://www.sefaria.org/Mishneh_Torah%2C_Human_Dispositions.4.5?ven=Sefaria_Community_Translation&lang=bi and see the commentaries there...

Comment: @RabbiKaii [Kitzur_Shulchan_Arukh 151:2](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Kitzur_Shulchan_Arukh.151.2?lang=bi&lang2=en),[4](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Kitzur_Shulchan_Arukh.151.4?lang=bi&lang2=en) more explicitly bring avoiding having a full stomach of food and sleeping in certain positions, as remedies against bringing on an erection (שלא יבוא לידי קשוי).

Comment: @Dov פניני הלכה, שמחת הבית וברכתו ד׳:ו׳
 ובכל אופן, גם צדיקים שמצליחים לשלוט על מחשבותיהם ביום, רואים מעת לעת קרי, מפני שכך הוא טבעו של הגוף שמייצר זרע, וככל שעוברים הימים, הגוף מתעורר יותר להוציאו. ודבר זה קורה לצעירים בתדירות גבוהה מאשר אצל מבוגרים. (דין איסור אוננות והרהורי עבירה לנשים יבואר להלן י-יב)

Comment: @TamirEvan pinging you too